# Is it possible to integrate a Unity app into an iOS app?

Tags: ios, swift, unity-game-engine

I have a Unity app that I made some time ago and am having a school project about related subject (chess game) in Swift.

I'm aware that iOS is compatible with Unity in running a whole Unity app, but is it possible to integrate both apps: I click on a Swift button called "3d scenario", and it launches the Unity app within, then I click on "return" button in unity to dismiss it and return to previous iOS app (either previous view or main menu, doesn't matter).

I can't find any help on the subject, but if it is possible. Could you briefly explain how the launch and "exit" functions are done?
Also the same question for Unity within android if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The possible way to do so is to export it in Unity to the platform of choice, IOS or Android, then embed the source in your app.